# Loading a page into a div through Ajax returns errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

I am currently attempting to load a specific part of a page into a div using Ajax:

```html
$(document).on("click", "#claim_forum_groups", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/user/{{ $user->id }}/groups",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: {
            subtype: 'claim_groups',
            type: 'forum_account'
        },
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') }
    })
   .done(function (data) {                      
        if(data == "success")
        {
            $("#forum_info_container").load(location.href + " #forum_info_container");
            $("#forum_data_container").load(location.href + " #forum_data_container");
            alert("good");
        }
    })
   .fail(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert("bad");
    });
});
```

What currently happens is, is fairly strange. At times, it loads both divs properly. When I re-try to "stress-test" everything, it just loads "forum_info_container" and when I check the Network tab, it shows an error of undefined stdClass index "id" which is used in the view.

Even when I test it, ID **is** defined, because when I refresh  the page everything looks fine. It seems to be working at times and sometimes it doesn't. My guess is that the .load() works too early or something of a kind. I tried using setTimeOut but it didn't remedy the situation.

This is my forum_data_container div for reference:

```
<div class="card-body mb-3" style="padding-top:0px" id="forum_data_container">
        @if(!is_null($info))
            <div class="post-meta mb-2">
                 Posts - {{ $info->id }}
            </div>
            <div class="post-meta mb-2">
                 Stats - {{ $info->id }}
            </div>
        @else
            No info available.
        @endif
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#forum_info_container").load(window.location + " #forum_info_container");
$("#forum_data_container").load(window.location + " #forum_data_container");
```

Comment: Now it's the opposite. forum_info_container is not loading.